# Factoring $1-(x+x²+x³+x⁴+x⁵)$

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions, roots

I calculated the generating function $G$ of the recurrence:

$$F(0)=0$$
$$F(1)=F(2)=F(3)=F(4)=1$$
$$F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)+F(n-3)+F(n-4)+F(n-5)$$

I got:

$$G(x)=\frac{x+x²+x³+x⁴}{1-(x+x²+x³+x⁴+x⁵)}$$

I want to expand this into a series to find the coefficients $\left[ X^n \right] G(X)$. But I can't find a simple way of factoring the denominator of $G(x)$. Here is what I've done so far:

$$S=1-(x+x²+x³+x⁴+x⁵)$$
$$xS=x-(x+x²+x³+x⁴+x⁵+x⁶-x)=x-(S+x⁶-x)$$
$$S(x+1)=2x-x⁶$$
$$S=\frac{2x-x⁶}{x+1}$$

This tells that $0$ is a root of $S$ but plugging $0$ back into $S$ gives $1$! I want hints.

Comment: The line $xS=x-(S+x^6-x)$ is wrong. It should be $xS=x-(1-S+x^6-x)$.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake. The correct term should be:
$$S=1-(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$$
$$xS=x-(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)=x-(1-S-x+x^6)=2x-x^6-1+S$$
$$S=\frac{2x-x^6-1}{x-1}$$
Therefore $x=0$ is not a root. In fact, the only real root of $S$ is: $$x\sim 0.50866$$

Comment: Should be $2x-x^6-1+S$ in the second line I think!

Comment: @L.F. - thanks :)

Comment: To factor S, one also needs the 4 complex other roots.

Comment: @Did - Of course. Unfortunately, none of the roots can be found analytically. I just mentioned the real one to contrast the OP's solution $x=0$.